# How to launch Navigation activity using Intent on Android

Tags: android, android-intent, android-maps

I want to start Navigation from my activity. The requirement is that when the user clicks the directions button in my app it should start the Navigation app on Android device and show the directions from current position to the destination position.

I have done this for Maps, where I am displaying the directions on the map and launching the Map activity, but now I want to launch the navigation and, without any user interaction, to display the route with the from and to geo locations.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is the code you need:

```
Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("google.navigation:q=Berlin Germany")); 
startActivity(i);
```

Comment: does this will show the directions from current location to Berlin Germany?

Comment: yes and it will also starts the navigation.

Comment: Ok, I will test it and will post my comments..thanks for the quick replies